# Using a while loop instead of a for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, while-loop

I've been asked to write a basic program for a class in Python using a for loop to print the average of 3 numbers from user input.

I've come up with the following:

```
num1 = raw_input("Please enter your first number: ")
num2 = raw_input("Please enter your second number: ")
num3 = raw_input("Please enter your third number: ")

my_list = [float(num1), float(num2), float(num3)]

total = 0

for i in my_list:
    total += i
    average = total / len(my_list)

print("They average of the 3 numbers is: " + str(average))
```

As a second question, I have been asked to re-write this code using a while loop instead of a for loop. Can anyone tell me how this can work? Thanks

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Comment: Give it a go! See what you can pull out of the bag?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is simple:

```
i = 0
total = 0
while i < len(my_list):
    total += my_list[i]
    average = total / len(my_list)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your exercise like that and use while loop:

```
  NUM = 3 
  count = 1 
  my_list = []
  while True:
      input_num = raw_input("Please enter number {}: ".format(count))
      my_list.append(float(input_num))
      if count == NUM:
          break
      count += 1

  average = sum(my_list) / NUM 
  print("They average of the {} numbers is: {}".format(NUM, average))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice approach

Comment: You can at least replace that while+counter loop by `for i in xrange(1, NUM+1):` (py2) or `for i in range(1, NUM+1):` (py3). This way, you don't have to create, increment and check+break yourself the counter (that I renamed `i`). As a rule of thumb, if you're doing a while+counter loop in Python, you're doing it wrong. There are still a few cases that may need it, but it's edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

*Can anyone tell me how this can work?*  Ask what is the difference between the two types of loop:

A `for` loop *iterates* through a sequence

A `while` loop tests for the truthfulness of a condition

Therefore they are used for different purposes.  Personally I would (do) teach `while` before `for`.

You *can* use a `while` loop, but you have to do the iteration yourself:

```
i = 0
total = 0

while i < len(my_list):
    total += my_list[i]
    i += 1

average = total / len(my_list)
```

Note that the calculation of `average` is outside the loop.

Query:  why are you teaching the old python 2.7?

Comment: Many thanks for this. The university course I'm taking is being taught through python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !

***Code :***

```
num1 = input("Please enter your first number: ")
num2 = input("Please enter your second number: ")
num3 = input("Please enter your third number: ")

my_list = [float(num1), float(num2), float(num3)]

total = 0
i=0
while (i<len(my_list)):
    total += my_list[i]
    i=i+1
average = total / len(my_list)

print("They average of the 3 numbers is: " + str(average))
```

***Output :***

```
Please enter your first number:  2
Please enter your second number:  3
Please enter your third number:  4
They average of the 3 numbers is: 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We do not use the same paradigms in Python. I'm pretty saddened to see all these "answers" using for/while loops.

This would be more pythonic (the Python Way):

```
average = sum(my_list) / len(my_list)
```

In Python we rarely (almost never) do the classic C for-loop (it is actually not implemented in the language). If you happen to do one, it's most likely that you're doing something wrong.

You can check this (and other R. Hettinger's) videos to get a grasp as to why. This core dev explains clearly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go